# Українська мова в російськомовному оточенні

Tags: соціолінгвістика

Людина, яка вирішила перейти з іншої мови на українську, часто зустрічається з тим, що більшість оточення спілкується звичною для цього регіону мовою.

В сучасній Україні — це регіони з традиційною російськомовною більшістю. В переважно російськовному Дніпрі я перейшов на українську, тож мало не щодня доводиться зустрічатись з наступними факторами:

- **Ігнорування** *(найпопулярніше)*. На українські репліки відповідабть російською, діалог ведеться двома мовами.
- **Перепитування**. Люди перепитують, не розуміючи, чому їм не відповідають російською.
- **Вибачення**. Час від часу офіціанти в кафе або таксисти вибачаються, що хотіли б спілкуватись українською, але не знають досконало мови. Популярна причина — відсутність практики, коли ні з ким практикуватись.
- **Нерозуміння** *(рідко)*. Зустрічаються люди, які не розуміють української (зазвичай, іноземці).
- **Агресія** *(дуже рідко)*. Співрозмовник наполягає на використанні російської, бо йому незрозуміло.
- **Страх** (одиничні випадки). В Севастополі (ще до анексії), коли я запитував щось у старших людей, деякі з незрозумілих причин лякались.

Повертатись до російської для побутового спілкування бажання немає. З іншого боку, щоденно відчувати дискомфорт в більшості випадків — теж неприємно.

**Прошу ваших порад**: як комфортно спілкуватись українською мовою в російськомовному оточенні?

Comment: **По-перше**, це соціологічне питання, воно мало стосується самої української мови. Замініть *українську* у запитанні на *кримтатарську* і отримаєте те саме запитання. **По-друге**, це запитання is opinion-based, бо воно запрошує до обговорення *необмеженого списку* проблем (і вирішень цих проблем). Наприклад, у фразі *«Люди перепитують, не розуміючи, чому їм не відповідають російською»* ми не знаємо достеменно (хоча і здогадуємося), що то за люди, і з яких причин вони «перепитують». Запитання передбачає, що ми можемо прочитати чиїсь думки, зрозуміти їхні мотиви, і запропонувати рішення.

Answer (score 7):

Я й сам голосуватиму за закриття цього питання, бо не формат.

Але відповім, як можу, зі свого досвіду. І хай цю відповідь теж мінусують )

У кожного своя ситуація, і дати якусь загальну пораду вкрай складно.

**Перепитування**: охоче вірю, що люди справді просто не сприймають з першого разу. Чесно, коли я не очікую англійської, то мені правда просто треба, щоб повторили. Людям просто можуть не зрозуміти. Це стосується й водіїв у маршрутках. Ніби різниця невелика "Михайлівська" чи "Міхайлафская", проте воно звучить незвично, і водій ніби прокидається з питанням "що?" просто через те, що прозвучало щось незвичне.

**Вибачення**: заохочуйте як можете. Кажіть, що ви за те, щоб практикувалися з вами, і не проти чути геть недосконалу мову.

**Нерозуміння**: я зовсім жорстокий, і пропоную переходити на англійську. А не знають англійської - ну то й не треба. Але в мене такі ситуації ніколи не виникали, коли мені справді щось треба було від людини. Тоді б перейшов на російську, напевно... Знову ж таки - гадки не маю, знаєти ви англійську чи ні, наскільки вам потрібно з цими людьми розмовляти тощо.

**Агресія**, **Страх**: може не варто з такими людьми спілкуватися?..

**Ігнорування** в мене дискомфорту не викликає. Я, фактично, так живу :)

Прикро, що у вашому списку немає **спроб перейти на українську** (зі мною аж дві людини переходили на жахливу українську за два роки - дуже приємно). Набагато частіше зустрічаю **явну пасивну підтримку української** - люди обов'язково скажуть або "дякую", або "до побачення" - одне-два слова, але дуже тепло. Ну й декілька людей переходило на чудову українську, що теж підтримує.

Ну і не можу не сказати, що неймовірно допомагає те, що дружина зі мною перейшла на українську. Не можу уявити, наскільки це було б складнішим, якби не ця підтримка.

Comment: а ще, окрім "дякую" і "до побачення" іноді просто за тобою повторюють. Наприклад, питаєш "а ти про це ніколи не замислювалася?", а тобі у відповідь, "замислювалася... звісно". Тобто, спрацьовують автоматичні процеси. Хочу щось прочитати про нейролінгвістику, щоби бути в змозі це ще й научно пояснити.

Answer (score 4):

Як я зрозумів, проблема лише в першому найпопулярнішому факторі — "На українські репліки відповідабть російською, діалог ведеться двома мовами", тому розглядатиму його.

Чому вас це бентежить? Ви хочете, щоб **всі** навколо говорили українською, бо вам так хочеться чи ви не можете спілкуватися, коли опонент говорить іншою мовою? Якщо перше, гадаю, вам треба змінити оточення або місто, якщо ні — трошки потерпіть, згодом ви звикните, а потім ще й побачите, що частина російськомовних співрозмовників переходить з вами на українську (виявляється вони давно хотіли це зробити, але не вистачало духу). 
Змінюйте себе, але не силкуйте інших, це ефективніше ніж примушувати всіх навколо робити те, чого хочеться вам.

P.S. Вважаю, що урядовці та держслужбовці — єдиний виняток щодо примушування інших розмовляти державною мовою.

Comment: ще обслуговуючий персонал - вони повинні починати розмову державною, а потім, якщо до них звертаються іншою, переходити на іноземну за умови знання мови клієнта.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54866/discussion-between-p-vovk-and-oleg).