# Які поширені й "загальновживані" помилки вас дратують найбільше?

Tags: помилки

Всі ми добре з ними знайомі, чуємо майже щодня, і далеко не завжди знаходимо можливість "випустити тиск". На жаль, ці помилки у слововживанні, вживанні словосполучень - як реп'яхи: чіпляються до всіх. Як приклад:
"рахую" замість "вважаю".
Але є й більш тонкі проблемки :) От наприклад: стандартне українське "передплата" ніяк не годиться для визначення дії, яку ми робимо, щоб отримувати регулярні повідомлення з яких-небудь інтернет-ресурсів.

Якщо питання неформатне, прошу модераторів бути ласкавими і пояснити, як треба :)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Ось тут можна почитати, які питання та відповіді вважаються хорошими: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%96-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%96-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%96-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%96-good-questions-and-good-answers.

Comment: Стосовно питання, то це, на мою думку, так зване opinion-based питання. Ось тут в коментарях обговорюється, чому такі питання не зовсім підходять для даного ресурсу: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/832/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%96%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%96

Comment: А стосовно помилок, то перше, що спадає на думку, це "переїзджаємо" :)

Comment: Ваше питання слід розбити на декілька запитань. Два з них ви вже озвучили. Наприклад, «Як правильно: "рахую" чи "вважаю"?». В тексті запитання вкажіть контекст, приклади. Нехай вас не лякає кількість. На Ukr.SE можна задавати **безліч** запитань, за умови, що вони не повторюють одне інше і є конкретними.

Comment: Я скопіюю сюди [коментар bytebuster](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/832/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%96%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%96#comment2206_832) з обговорення, на яке вже вище дали посилання: "<...> це запитання is opinion-based, бо воно запрошує до обговорення *необмеженого списку* проблем (і вирішень цих проблем)". Нам потрібні конкретні запитання, на які можна отримати відповідь у розумні терміни.

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka, до попереднього коментаря: запитання, які передбачають відповіді у вигляді відкритого (необмеженого) списку, заохочують до необмеженої кількості відповідей, кожна з яких міститиме **лише частину списку**, а отже, буде неповною, а значить, і неякісною. Ось, що погано.

Comment: сподіваюся, кількість таких помилок все ж обмежена )

Comment: сподіваюся ви зможете переформулювати питання так, щоб спільнота змогла на нього якісно відповісти.